# how to alter a portion of a value of an attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a bit of a tricky one.  I'm trying to alter just a portion of the string that is assigned to style. I would like to use js to change the 50% in the two gradient clauses to different values without having to create the entire string in js.

Is there some sort of regex exchange in conjunction with `setAttribute`?

```
<a class="item" id="bob" style="
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 255, 0) 0%, rgb(250, 250, 5) 50%, rgb(252, 3, 3) 100%);
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 255, 0) 0%, rgb(250, 250, 5) 50%, rgb(252, 3, 3) 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00ff00',endColorstr='#fc0303',GradientType=1);">MYtext</a>
```

Comment: you have the benefit of knowing the exact offset of that portion of the string. It shouldn't be hard to isolate beginning there. Naturally we have to ask "what have you tried"

Comment: I have no idea how to isolate it but I have tried this sort of thing. But no luck.  Was looking for something a little more straight forward.
<input type="button" name="sue" 
value="80%"      onclick="document.getElementById('bob').style='background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 255, 0) 0%, rgb(250, 250, 5)' + this.value + ', rgb(252, 3, 3) 100%);'">
</input>

Comment: and what did this do for you? besides error cause on= is invalid. You may have meant onclick or something. Supposing that were right, what results did this give you?

Comment: Sorry was mid edit.
It did nothing. No change

Answer (score 0):

Argh!

```
var el = document.getElementById('bob');
el.setAttribute('style', el.getAttribute('style').replace('50%', '30%'));
```

But this would be better:

```
var el = document.getElementById('bob');
el.style.backgroundImage = el.style.backgroundImage.replace(/50%/g, '30%');
```

Comment: Because manipulating styles as attribute strings feels wrong.

Comment: :)  It might feel wrong but I can't figure out any other way to dynamically alter the gradient.  I tried your code but still have not got it to work.  I'll add the index in the next comment as it is short.

Comment: `code`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>   
<script type="text/javascript">
function setgrad() {
var el = document.getElementsById('bob');
el.setAttribute('style', el.getAttribute('style').replace('50%', '75%'));}</script></head>   
<body> <a id="bob" style="background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 255, 0) 0%, rgb(250, 250, 5) 50%, rgb(252, 3, 3) 100%);">MYTEXT</a>    
<input type="button" name="Btn" value="30%" onclick="setgrad();"> TEST</input></body></html>`

Comment: Sorry.  Tried to clean up the formatting to be more readable but got timed out.

Comment: @user2247282 Sorry, typo! Also, see a second suggestion above. Demo: http://jsbin.com/iyehij/2/edit. Also using a regular expression to replace multiple occurrences of "50%".

Comment: ahha. I was too tired to catch that 's'.  Great! it works perfectly now.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2247282 Yeah, I was using document.getElementsByTagName while testing, and forgot to remove the "s" when changed to ById. That was stupid...

Answer (score 0):

The `style` property is an object, not a string. So you'd have to do something like:

```
var bob = document.getElementById('bob');

var background = bob.style.backgroundImage;

if (background) {
    bob.style.backgroundImage = background.replace('50%','70%');
}
```

You can also use `setAttribute` on the `style` object if you like:

```
bob.style.setAttribute('backgroundImage' ...
```

but `setAttribute` doesn't work reliably (or works differently) on IE when dealing with `style` objects. Just use the much shorter and more reliable object access syntax instead:

```
bob.style.backgroundImage = ...
```

---

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know setAttribute is not reliable. I prefer object refs anyways so that works out nicely.  Both you and bfavaretto converged on the same solution.  Thanks.